# Select only files with QFileDialog [PyQT]

Tags: qt, pyqt, qfiledialog

I'm trying to use the QFileDialog widget in PyQT in order to get the name of a file to save results. I'm using the method QFileDialog.getSaveFileName() and, as is expected, if I select an existing file a warning box appears saying that the file exists and offering the possibility to overwrite it. But the problem is that if I select a directory instead of a regular file the same warning box as if it was a normal file appears. I don't like this behavior and I would like a warning box informing there is a directory and it can't be selected, or maybe the OK button disabled until a regular file is selected. Is possible to do? How can I do this, if it is possible?

Thanks

Comment: I am surprised that you don't instead enter said directory when you OK it. However, to answer your question, if you want custom behaviour in a file dialog, you'll have to subclass rather than use the convenience methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand the first sentence in your comment. I don't know if I did a bad explanation. The "problem" is that if I select a directory instead of a regular file, a QFileDialog object accepts it as valid, and I need (if possible and fast) that the dialog accepts only regular files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static functions will open a *native* dialog, unless you set [DontUseNativeDialog](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) with the options parameter, in which case you will get the built-in Qt file-dialog:

```
    path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
```

The built-in dialog is often faster, and generally has more sensible behaviour than the native dialogs. In particular, if you single-click a directory, the **Save** button changes to an **Open** button, so a directory can never be selected.

If you absolutely *must* have an native dialog, you could try setting the [DontConfirmOverwrite](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) option. This will allow you to handle any potential overwriting yourself after the dialog has closed.